# GZip compression on HTTP Request with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gzip, client-server

I'm new to using Tomcat so perhaps I'm missing something.  In the server.xml it looks as though it is possible to enable GZip compression for HTTP Responses from the server to the client.  However in my application, there are large chunks of XML data being sent from the client to the server.  Is there a way to enable GZip compression in tomcat so that my client sends the data compressed and it is automatically decompressed on the server side?  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of client are you talking about? Is it just a web browser?

Comment: is your client sending the HTTP header "Accept-Encoding: gzip" ? Could you show a trace of the request response being sent over the wire?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this [2Way HTTP Compression Servlet Filter](http://www.thomas-bayer.com/gzip-compression-filter.htm) would be helpful?

Comment: I saw that when doing my research.  So is adding a servlet filter the appropriate way to go when using Tomcat?  I am surprised that there isn't some native support in Tomcat for compressing HTTP requests.  Especially with web-services where the client can be sending a large amount of data.

Comment: Doesn't seem to properly support `ETag` nor `Content-Length`. (they are untouched, they should be modified)

Answer (score -1):

this works for me. see the link below.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the solution on the link you provided is to enable gzip compression in the RESPONSE, not decompression in the REQUEST.
However, [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) (e.g. the article you linked might disappear and the answer would be useless)

Comment: The question is about how to enable decompression of requests, not compression of responses.